# can extra dimensions explain the non locality of entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, spacetime-dimensions, locality

This is the question of layman fascinated by quantum theory.
Entanglement of particles far apart from each other (relative to the speed of light) has been addressed in some other questions where the answer has been that it is simply a matter of correlation. 
In my mind this is an answer in mathematical terms that only confirm that the quantum calculations are correct. However, for me (and Einstein) that does not make it less puzzling that flipping a spin here can affect another spin at millions of year away.
My question is pretty naive: could this phenomenon be explained by some extra dimensions in which the two particles could behave as a spinning dipole (or a Cooper pair) that, when observed, assume one of two orientations?

Comment: why this (mute) downvote ? this is rude.

Comment: I believe that this is impossible, because it seems this would in principle be a local hidden variable model, which is more or less experimentally excluded nowadays. Also, as you say, entanglement is correlations, so there is exactly no "flipping the spin that affects another spin at millions of years away".

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET The downvote probably happened because 1) The first sentence of the post is irrelevant and distracting from the main point; 2) The reference to "some other questions" has no link. This is lazy on the part of the author. If the author can't take time to link to the references, who wants to spend time answering?; 3) This issue is addressed by Bell's inequality and things like this are asked all the time on this site. I still think it's *better* if down-voters post a comment, but we can't seriously expect them to if there are a lot of problems with a post.

Comment: yep, but the OP is not aware of all this past and context. For him it's his first attempt. Seriously I've seen tons of really worse "poor questions", with no effort at all. It's not the case here. Stackechange can be felt as very rude by newcomers.